# Replace vertical line with ">" in text copied from Mail and pasted to plain-text

Tags: mail.app

When I copy the text of an email from Mail into a plain-text document, it loses the vertical lines marking replied text. Is there any way to replace those vertical lines with ">" (greater-than signs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An OS X Service that reformats a forwarded Mail message with Markdown-style '>' quotes — https://github.com/smokris/MailToMarkdown